# Caché SQL - Convert Minute format to Hours

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I am working with a table that already exists that has columns formatted in some sort of a minute format. It looks like it was meant to be hh:mm, but it is not quite. For instance, where it should be 03:00, it says 01:80 for 180 minutes. Or for 1:30 it states 00:90. How can I convert these columns to an hh:mm format? Any help would be great, I'm struggling! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you've given enough information to answer the question.  How would your program know if 1:40 meant 100 minutes or 140 minutes?  Is at string of form "01:80" stored in the database or is something else stored in the database then formatted later?  You can try Select %INTERNAL(MyTimeColumn) to see the internal format.

Comment: It is stored as a string like you said: '01:80'. Which means three hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following elegant code:

```
SELECT ((myField*100)+RIGHT(myField,2))/60 
         || ':' 
         || RIGHT('00'(((myField*100)+RIGHT(myField,2))#60),2) 
From myTable
```

seems to work.